# java app goes too slow in android os

Tags: java, android, animation, sprites

The problem is that my java app contains too many animated sprites and it runs very slowly on android system.

Does the usage of .gif animation instead of sprite animation will improve the speed?
I really don't know which animation technique consume less CPU time.

Comment: Can you provide us some additional information on how you're displaying sprites?  For example, are you using SurfaceView?  Are you using RGB_565 for sprites? ARGB_4444?  Are you using pooling and recycling techniques?

Comment: In a main app loop I check for the delay between frames and post a part of a ARGB sprite sheet onto a surfaceView.

Comment: What you're really asking is how to optimize graphics performance on Android.  It's a big topic and there are many things you can do, but using a gif is not going to solve all your problems.

Comment: true but using gifs I don't have a connection of gif's speed with the java code, right? The question is still: will gifs improve a speed of the app or not?

Comment: I believe the answer is no or not significantly enough to resolve performance issue, but honestly, I've never seen a game using gifs, probably because of the lack of flexibility that would give you.

Comment: Grab a profiler and see what it tells you. There's no substitute for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you are able to render .gifs acceptable for your needs (frame timing, alpha channel) or not? 
It all depends on implementation. But the resulting app's size will not be reduced, if the device's memory is a considerable bottleneck.